# Vault Agent render multiple secrets in the template

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

I have couple of secrets in the vault and would like the vault agent annotations render multiple secrets into the same template. is this possible?? thanks

```
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-cos1.json: "aws/data/cosapikey1"
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-cos2.json: "aws/data/cosapikey2"
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-cos3.json: "aws/data/cosapike3"

#something like this
vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-cos.json: |
   {{`{{- with secret "aws/data/cosapikey" -}}
      {
        "raw":{
          "credential": {
            "apikey": "{{ .Data.data.cosapikey1 }}"
          }
        },
        "skiplist":{
          "credential": {
            "apikey": "{{ .Data.data.cosapikey2 }}"
          }
        },
        "twogen":{
          "credential": {
            "apikey": "{{ .Data.data.cosapikey3 }}"
          }
        }
      }
   {{- end -}}`}}
```